# Makefile: How do I concat, replace and put in a new file?

Tags: build, makefile

#### UPDATE

At the end, I came up with a lightening beautiful build Makefile. If you want take a look at this gist - https://gist.github.com/jonataswalker/5961bfcc0f335f3b51ea.

---

To concatenate some files I can do:

```
# JS files
JS_TARGETS = wrapper.js \
             file1.js \
             file2.js

combine-js:
    @cat $(JS_TARGETS) > file-combined.js
```

But that's not what I want/need. My `wrapper.js` is like:

```js
(function(Foo, win, doc){
  'use strict';

  /*{CODE_TO_BE_REPLACED}*/

})(window.Foo = window.Foo || {}, window, document);
```

So I need to put my other files inside `wrapper.js`. After that I will run  `jshint` and `uglify` but this is another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be splitting `wrapper.js` into two parts - head and tail - and then concatenating in strict order, e.g.:

```
cat wrapper_head.js file1.js file2.js wrapper_tail.js > file-combined.js
```

Comment: Indeed, the simplest solution, thanks. I'll upvote later, because I reached my daily limit.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it - it uses `perl` though:

```
JS_WRAPPED_SOURCES = file1.js file2.js
JS_WRAPPER = wrapper.js
JS_SOURCES = $(JS_WRAPPER) $(JS_WRAPPED_SOURCES)

combined.js: $(JS_SOURCES)
        cat $< | perl -e '$$c=join("\n",<>); $$c =~ s/{CODE_TO_BE_REPLACED}/`cat $(JS_WRAPPED_SOURCES)`/e; print $$c' \
         > $@
```

Since you're running `jshint` and `uglify` I'm guessing you're using `Grunt`.
In that case, I'd recommend you use a Grunt task like [grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace).

Comment: Many thanks, nice an clean but I chose @keltar's by simplicity. I'll upvote later, I reached my daily limit.

Comment: You're welcome! And yes, keep it simple, if possible!